# python zeep, how can I find out easier the binding a method/property belongs to?

Tags: python, soap-client, zeep

I try to use the python-zeep package to consume some soap service ([ID3 Global](http://www.id3globalsupport.com/Website/content/Sample%20Code/Web%20Dev%20Guide%20HTML/developers%20guide.html))

This seems doable, kudos for the recently added features (WSSE authentication and the possibility to use several bindings)

For now I try every binding in a cycle in order to find the right one, something like:

```
url = '{http://www.id3global.com/ID3gWS/2013/04}'
bindings = [key.replace(url, '') for key in client.wsdl.bindings]
for binding in bindings:
    try:
        service = client.bind('ID3global', binding)
        result = service.AuthenticateSP(
            ProfileIDVersion=profile_id_version,
            InputData=input_data
        )
        print("\n\nAuthenticateSP's result: {}\n\n".format(result))
    except Exception as exception:
        print('Exception: {}\n'.format(exception))
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to loop through all ports to find the one you need. You can inspect the wsdl or use `python -mzeep <wsdl>` to find which operation belongs to which port

Comment: Thanks. I try to get dynamically the right binding for an operation. Ok, I'll try to use python -mzeep <wsdl>.